# disable donotcachepage for woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce

I'm using woocommece and wp-rocket. I disabled Page Caching of rocket and just using minify. as default rocket don't cache checkout and cart because these pages used DONOTCACHEPAGE constant but now I want to enable cache for these pages too speedup by minify css and js. I think enabling that not make any problem because content cache is disable. Is it any way to enable cache for cart and checkout?

Answer (score 0):

hm, this isn't a difficult one as much as there really is a compatibility issue with combining the settings. I recommend using elementor & going into the settings of the individual block to really edit the settings of each per page. It'll take a long time, but everything on here really takes a long time to implement or problem solve regardless so I say give it a try